# How to convert User input (from dialog boxes) into arrays

Tags: java, arrays, dialog, average

I really need help with my program. I'm trying to make a cumulative grade calculator in java, using arrays and dialog boxes. For some reason, my arrays won't print out the input made by the user which is throwing off my calculations. How can I give it the correct value?

````
    {
        // First array - Length
        int[] arNumber = null;
        int number;
        String str;

        // Second array - Elements
        int numbers;
        int[] arNumbers = null;
        int total = 0;
        int gradeSum = 0;
        String str2;

        String message = "How many grades will you input in this class?";
        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
        number = Integer.parseInt(str);
        arNumber = new int[number];

        for(int index = 0; index < arNumber.length; index++)
        {
            String message2 = "Insert your grade";
            str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message2);
            numbers = Integer.parseInt(str2);
            arNumbers = new int[numbers];

        }
        for (int element : arNumbers)
        {
            // Print array onto console
            System.out.println(element);

            // Add all elements 
            gradeSum += element;

            // Print grade onto console
            System.out.println(gradeSum);
        }

        total = gradeSum / arNumber.length;

        return total;

    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't need to use two arrays. The line with `arNumbers = new int[numbers];` means that `arNumbers` is getting reinitialized as a new array for every iteration of that loop. Try using `arNumber[index] = numbers;` to assign the user-entered value into the `arNumber` array and do away with `arNumbers`. Then loop over `arNumber` in the second loop.

Also note that `total` is declared as an `int` which will truncate your floating point value, which I'm guessing you don't want. Good luck!